# Nice Work Shoes That Won't Get Messed up in Toe-Clips

Tags: commuter, shoes

I'm a commuter and I'm looking for shoes that won't get totally messed up by my pedal toe clips.

I've been using something [similar to these](http://www.lordandtaylor.com/webapp/wcs/stores/servlet/en/lord-and-taylor/blackley-leather-boat-shoes?gclid=CM_Q5bK6nroCFQkSMwodaGoAUg). Any other suggestions?

Comment: Personally, I just keep a separate pair of shoes at the office, as office  shoes aren't really optimized for cycling, and my shoes always end up wet when it rains.

Comment: I'm not sure how you commute, but I'd say keeping your work shoes in your bag and using some other shoes is a good idea. But with those, it looks like just using plain ole' platform pedals instead would be fine for a short commute - do you really need/want the toe clips?

Comment: I suggest having a separate pair of shoes for commuting. Comfortable commuting shoes != comfortable work shoes, for multiple reasons.

Answer (score 2):

Don't change the shoes, change the pedal. A hybrid pedal would satisfy both needs. It features a clip and a flat "normal shoes" side. Because for commuting sport-like conditions are probably not so important.

http://bike.shimano.com/publish/content/global_cycle/en/us/index/products/pedals/mountain/product.-code-PD-A530.-type-.pd_mountain.html

greets Josef

Comment: I have these pedals. They are great if you have one bike, and don't want to ride clipped all the time. I ride clipped when commuting or for exercise, but when I just want to go to the store, I can ride with regular shoes.

Comment: Alternatively, if the user is using a fixed gear drivetrain and needs to have foot retention, then using something like hold fast pedal straps on bmx style platform pedals is another good option and can be used with most types of shoes.

Comment: If the user is not on a fixed gear drivetrain, then just using flat pedals is fine too.

Answer (score 1):

Check out [Chrome Industries](http://www.chromeindustries.com/us/en/footwear), they make a lot of commuter apparel and have a whole line of clip and non-clip shoes. I'm not sure how dressy you need, but these might work for you. Plus if you ever decided to go with clipless pedals you'll have shoes!

Answer (score 0):

If keeping a 2nd pair of shoes at work isn't an option your best bet would probably be to get overshoes.

[image: overshoes]

This should stop your toe clips from scuffing up your shoes.

Comment: But these will cook your feet when temperature is more than a few degrees over the freezing point.

Comment: You can get "summer" or "light" overshoes as well as "winter" ones. I assume a commute is a relatively short distance at a slow / moderate pace so overheating shouldn't be too much of an issue.

Comment: Maybe we have different ideas of commuting ;)

Comment: Or this: http://www.amazon.com/Totes-Geometric-Overshoe-Size-9-5/dp/B002NWZLTS

Comment: Durability is something to worry about with these things from what I've seen.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest just using a cheap pair of rubber "over shoes" designed for wearing in the rain to protect shoes. These are inexpensive and if it does rain, you're ready for inclement weather. These should keep your work shoes from getting marked up by the toe clips.

Answer (score 0):

If you want foot retention without switching to clipless shoes, you could use pedal straps (like [these](http://restrap.co.uk/shop/diagonal-straps), or [these](http://www.ynotcycle.com/products/pedal-straps/), or just search for "pedal straps").

They're fabric rather than metal or resin, so should do less damage to your work shoes.